# Click and mousemove (changing color multiple targets)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, mousemove

```
$(function(){
    var isMouseClicked=false;
    $("#diody td.LED").click(function(){
        if(wybrany_kolor=="red"){
            $(this).css("background-image","url(led_red2.png)")
            .css("transition", "all 0.25s ease-in-out");
            $('.LED').mousedown(function(){
                isMouseClicked = true;  
               });
               $("#app").mouseup(function(){
               isMouseClicked = false;
               });
               $(".LED").mousemove(function(){
                   if(isMouseClicked){
                     $(this).css("background-image","url(led_red2.png)")
                     .css("transition", "all 0.25s ease-in-out");
                   }
               });                  
        }
    });
    $("#diody td.LED").click(function(){
        if(wybrany_kolor=="yellow"){
        $(this).css("background-image","url(led_yellow.png)")
        .css("transition", "all 0.25s ease-in-out");
        $('.LED').mousedown(function(){
            isMouseClicked = true;  
           });
           $("#app").mouseup(function(){
           isMouseClicked = false;
           });
           $(".LED").mousemove(function(){
               if(isMouseClicked){
                 $(this).css("background-image","url(led_yellow.png)")
                 .css("transition", "all 0.25s ease-in-out");
               }
           });
        }
    });
```

I have sth like this. What i expect : when i click on "LED" it needs to change kolor, when i click on "LED" and move mouse over others "LEDs" their need to change color to same color. 
Problem is: its working with one color, but when i change color to another for example from red to yellow and  click(keep mouse clicked) and  move over others it is changing color but on red (should be yellow). If i click once its change color property, and then i can click and move mouse and its working good. Problem is in first color change.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Q8dU/

diody- its table filled with td.LED (sth like chess).

EDIT:
SOLVED

```
$(function () {
var isMouseClicked=false;
var $led = $('.LED').click(function(){
    if(wybrany_kolor=="red")$(this).css("background-image","url(led_red2.png)");
    else if(wybrany_kolor=="yellow")$(this).css("background-image","url(led_yellow.png)");
    else if(wybrany_kolor==green)$(this).css("background-image","url(led_green.png)");
    })
    .mousedown(function(){ isMouseClicked=true;})
    .mousemove(function () {
    if(isMouseClicked){
        if(wybrany_kolor=="red")$(this).css("background-image","url(led_red2.png)");
        else if(wybrany_kolor=="yellow")$(this).css("background-image","url(led_yellow.png)");
        else if(wybrany_kolor==green)$(this).css("background-image","url(led_green.png)");
    }
});
$(document).mouseup(function () {
    isMouseClicked=false;
})
```

Comment: Can you set up a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding how event handlers attach. You have:

```
$("#diody td.LED").click(function(){ ...
```

Listed twice in the code, each with different handlers. That's two functions that will fire for each matching selector. Even if that's what you want, that's a wildly confusing way to go about it.

Next up you have $('.LED').mouse* handlers inside these click handlers. That's going to cause a cumulative effect of attaching n-clicked mouse event handlers.

I think your design needs refactoring.

Comment: I had one: $("#diody td.LED").click(function(){ ...  before for all colors and it was working same. How to solve this? Do one function with click, mousedown, mouseup etc and inside this IF(color) ?